# Removing tab indent in ipython shell

Tags: python, ipython

My question is that how can I **remove a tab indent in IPython shell** without using backspace four times?

Answer (score 2):

Bilal. I'm new to Stackoverflow.

According to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kidpixo/f4318f8c8143adee5b40), Command-[ should dedent in edit mode. If this doesn't work, please let me know.